# Search Macro gives error stating, "You can't use Find or Replace" when search is used and focus is lost before search is complete

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Using macro button in form to search database. My database is quite large, so that can take 10-20 seconds depending on how good my VPN connection is. I frequently use a few programs together and switch between windows. If I initiate a search, then change focus to another program, Access will give me an error when it regains focus. Is there any way to suppress this? It's quite annoying and not at all helpful. I inherited this database and I don't have a lot of experience using macros. Googling has not been helpful.

Here is the code for the macro:

```
OnError
       Go to   Next
    Macro Name

GoToControl
    Control Name =[Screen].[PreviousControl].[Name]

Clear MacroError

RunMenuCommand
      Command   Find

If   [MacroError]<>0   Then
      MessageBox
            Message =[MacroError].[Description]
               Beep   Yes
               Type   None
               Title
End If
```

EDIT: In place of the screenshot here is the error dialogue:

> **You can't use Find or Replace now.** 
> The fields are not searchable due to one of the following: 
> *The fields are controls (such as buttons or OLE objects). 
> *The fields have no data. 
> *There are no fields to search.

TYIA

Comment: Your screenshot is not displaying. Post error message as text.

Comment: I replaced the screenshot with the text of the error message.                                                                  

Obviously waiting for Access to finish its search is a foolproof way to keep the error message from appearing. It really is not an option since I would lose quite a bit of time waiting for Access to complete the search before going to Excel to copy the qualitative data I need to enter into Access, or not doing other work that I need to get done. If it cannot be suppressed then the error is just something I will have to work around.